# How can I convert video to DivX4 to play on my Kogan TV?

Tags: avconv

I want to convert some videos to play on my Kogan TV using a portable hard-drive, but I am having trouble getting it to work. Most of my avi files, encoded using as xvid, all come up as 'unsupported file' on the TV.

The only file that I've found that works is reported as being the following by `file`:

```
test.avi:  RIFF (little-endian) data, AVI, 640 x 464, 23.98 fps, video: DivX 4, audio: MPEG-1 Layer 3 (stereo, 48000 Hz)
```

But I can't seem to work out a suitable `avconv` command line to convert anything else to that format.

The TV claims to support (from [here](http://help.kogan.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/117/0/my-tv-does-not-play-back-my-video-files-it-says-unsupported-file)):

> AVI (MPEG - 1/2 and MPEG-4 divx 4 coded) and MP4 (MPEG - 1/2 and MPEG-4 divx 4 coded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I just needed to trick the TV into thinking it was the DivX codec when it is really the xvid codec, by changing the video tag (or [FourCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FourCC%20FourCC) to `DIVX`) using `-tag:v DIVX`:

```
avconv -i input.mp4 -c:v libxvid -c:a libmp3lame -b 700k -tag:v DIVX output.avi
```

Which seems to be acceptable to the TV, and `file` now outputs similar to my good video:

```
output.avi: RIFF (little-endian) data, AVI, 640 x 480, 25.00 fps, video: DivX 4, audio: MPEG-1 Layer 3 (stereo, 44100 Hz)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some media players don't support Divx format but can read Xvid

In my case, i used avconv to set the correct tag and let my media player read it as Xvid and not Divx :

```
$ avconv -i input.avi -vtag Xvid -c:a copy -c:v copy output.avi
```

After that :

```
$ file input.avi
input.avi: RIFF (little-endian) data, AVI, 640 x 360, 23.98 fps, video: DivX 4, audio: MPEG-1 Layer 3 (stereo, 48000 Hz)
$ file output.avi
output.avi: RIFF (little-endian) data, AVI, 640 x 360, 23.98 fps, video: XviD, audio: MPEG-1 Layer 3 (stereo, 48000 Hz)
```

Comment: The question is about converting files to DivX not from DivX format. Please revise your answer accordingly.